# Frobenius method giving y=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I'm trying to solve $$y^{''}+\bigg(-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3}\bigg)y=0$$
using Frobenius method. What I did is following:
$$y=\sum_{i=0}a_ix^{i+k}$$
$$y^{''}=\sum_{i=0}(i+k+2)(i+k+1)a_{i+2}x^{i+k}$$
and the original equation after some rearangment becomes
$$\sum_{i=0}((i+k+2)(i+k+1)a_{i+2}-a_{i+1}+a_{i+3})x^{i+k}-\frac{a_0}{x}x^k+\frac{a_0}{x^3}x^k+\frac{a_1}{x^2}x^k+\frac{a_2}{x}x^k=0$$

Now comparing the coefficient in the above equation straightaway gives $$a_0=0$$
$$a_1=0$$
$$a_2=a_0$$

Now if I used the summation term I get $a_3=0$ from its first term and from the next term $a_4=0$, same goes for all the higher terms.

So ultimately I'm getting $y=0$ which is wrong. Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Note that, as stated (e.g., with no initial condition to indicate otherwise), $y(x) = 0$ **is** a solution to your differential equation.

Comment: @JohnOmielan so unless I impose initial conditions I cannot proceed further but for all the cases that I have used Frobenius method the initial condition boils down to allocating the value of either $a_0$ or $a_1$ (for 2nd order ODE). As for the solution $y=0$ it is the trivial solution of a homogenous ODE.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to believe there exists any solutions to this differential equation other than the trivial one of $y(x) = 0$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Well the reason it has to have a solution is because it's an approximate ODE of [this].(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578435/can-frobenius-method-method-be-used-to-solve-following-ode)

Comment: Your equation does not have a regular singularity at $x=0$, so there is no reason why Frobenius should work. Note that the approximation you use is for $|x|\gg1$ while the Frobenius method tries to find an approximation for $|x|\ll 1$ where your source uses a regular power series for the arctan.

Comment: $x = 0$ and $x = \infty$ are irregular singular points. You can find asymptotic approximations for solutions around those points in the form $\exp(A x^\alpha) Y(x)$, where $Y(x)$ will be a series in fractional powers of $x$ (not a Frobenius series).