# Can Frobenius method method be used to solve following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I'm trying to solve following ODE $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y\tan^{-1}(x)=0$$ But the power series of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is actually divided in there regions [here.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Series_Expansion_for_Real_Arctangent_Function) Moreover, this ODE doesn't have the standard form as given in [wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)

I tried to do it in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578356/frobenius-method-giving-y-0) but it is not coming out to be useful.

Comment: You get a result like the Airy function, exponentially growing on one side, oscillating on the other. Only that the exponent stays linear(ly bounded), not quadratic, as the equation comes close to $y''\pm\frac\pi2 y=0$ for $x\to\pm\infty$.